# Scrolling in Xamarin Forms SfListView causes NullReferenceException in iOS Main function

Tags: ios, listview, xamarin.forms, syncfusion

I just had a *very* weird issue in my app.
I was adding Syncfusion's SfListView to some pages in my app and for some reason, if the first thing I do when a page that uses the SfListView loads is scroll the ListView, I get a NullReferenceException...in the UIApplication.Main() function that gets called in the iOS project's Main class. There's nothing special in that class at all, though.
It gets better. If I do something else first, like dragging and dropping the items in the SfListView to reorder them and *then* I scroll it, it doesn't throw the exception.
What on Earth could be causing this?

Here is the XAML for one of the pages that uses the SfListView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:syncfusion="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.ListView.XForms;assembly=Syncfusion.SfListView.XForms"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="Partylist.Views.EventsPage"
             Title="Events"
             BackgroundColor="White">
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem IconImageSource="settings_gear.png"
                     Priority="0"/>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <!--Main layout of the page-->
        <StackLayout>
            <!--ListView of the events-->
            <syncfusion:SfListView x:Name="EventsListView"
                                   SelectionMode="Single"
                                   SelectionGesture="Tap"
                                   SelectionChanged="OnItemSelected"
                                   DragStartMode="OnHold">
                <syncfusion:SfListView.DragDropController>
                    <syncfusion:DragDropController UpdateSource="True"/>
                </syncfusion:SfListView.DragDropController>
                <syncfusion:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <SwipeView>
                                <!--Swipe from the right to make some options 
                                appear-->
                                <SwipeView.RightItems>
                                    <SwipeItems>
                                        <SwipeItem Invoked="OnDelete"
                                                   CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                                   Text="Delete"
                                                   BackgroundColor="#ff418b"
                                                   IsDestructive="true"/>
                                        <SwipeItem Invoked="OnRename"
                                                   CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                                   Text="Rename"
                                                   BackgroundColor="#FF7700"/>
                                    </SwipeItems>
                                </SwipeView.RightItems>
                                <!--This is the content that actually appears-->
                                <StackLayout Padding="20,5">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding EventFolder.Name}"
                                           TextColor="#FF7700"
                                           FontSize="Large"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </SwipeView>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </syncfusion:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
            </syncfusion:SfListView>

            <!--"New Event" button-->
            <Button Text="+ Add New Event"
                    TextColor="#ff418b"
                    FontSize="Large"
                    BackgroundColor="#00ffffff"
                    Clicked="OnNewEventClicked"/>
            
            <!--The banner at the bottom of the screen that gives tips-->
            <Frame BorderColor="#ff418b"
                   Padding="0"
                   HeightRequest="75">
                <FlexLayout Direction="Row"
                            AlignItems="Stretch"
                            JustifyContent="SpaceBetween">
                    <!--The "Tip" icon-->
                    <Image Source="tip_icon.png"
                           Margin="10"
                           FlexLayout.Basis="50"/>
                    <!--The short version of the tip-->
                    <Label x:Name="tipLabel"
                           VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                           TextColor="#bb0099"
                           FontSize="Medium"
                           FontAttributes="Bold"
                           FlexLayout.Basis="240"/>
                    <!--The button that opens up a screen 
                    with the rest of the tip-->
                    <Button Clicked="OnMoreClicked"
                            Text="More"
                            TextColor="White"
                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                            FontSize="Medium"
                            BackgroundColor="#ff418b"
                            FlexLayout.Basis="100"/>
                </FlexLayout>
            </Frame>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Here is the iOS project's Main class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using Foundation;
using UIKit;

namespace Partylist.iOS
{
    public class Application
    {
        // This is the main entry point of the application.
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // if you want to use a different Application Delegate class from "AppDelegate"
            // you can specify it here.
            UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate"); // This is the line that throws the exception.
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE: I just applied the SfListView to a couple more pages in my project and I couldn't type into the entries in the items on those pages' lists or use their SwipeViews (the experimental ones in Xamarin, not the ones from the SfListView) without crashing the app in the same way as above.

Comment: It's not that it's called int he main class, that's just where uncaught exceptions end up before crashing the app. Try downgrading to Xamarin Forms 4.6 if you're on 4.7. There's a known issue with the new clip masking renderer that was causing my apps to crash with Syncfusion stuff.

Comment: @BenReierson What version of 4.6? Because I just tried downgrading to 4.6.1073 and it didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got rid of the Synfcusion ListView and switched back to the one that Xamarin comes with. @BenReierson said it's a problems with Xamarin, so maybe I'll look into switching back when that bug gets fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Glad to inform that the reported issue “NullReferenceException throws when scrolling the SfListView with DragDropController” has been included in Syncfusion's latest Weekly NuGet release update version **18.2.0.46** which is available for download (https://www.nuget.org/).